# PTBR (Spinner) Firebase Exception: Found conflicting getters for name: getAdapter

Tags: firebase, android-adapter, spinners, getters-setters, realtime-database

Estou fazendo uma aplicação onde eu escolho um numero no spinner e gravo esse numero no Firebase. esta dando o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

detalhes sobre o spinner e como estou gravando no firebase

```
spinnercarrinho = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_carrinho);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.carrinho_string, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinnercarrinho.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinnercarrinho.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            objetoRef.child("carrinho").child("spinnercarrinho").setValue(spinnercarrinho);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está passando a View Spinner para o Firebase. Enquantp devia passar o valor obtido do Spinner:

```
objetoRef.child("carrinho").child("spinnercarrinho").setValue(spinnercarrinho.getSelectedItem().toString());
```